# combinations and probablity

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A committee of 5 members is selected randomly from 10 parents, 16 students and  4 teachers. how can one find the probability that a teacher will be the chairman if the first person selected is to be made chairman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a teacher to be Chair, we need to select a teacher on the first pick. How many people are there? How many teachers?  (The *size* of the committee is irrelevant.)

Comment: Is the answer 4/30?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$